# How to convert different date types into one in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a character column with dates that I need to convert to class "date". I've already tried doing the usual (as.Date, dmy etc) it always returns NA.

```
dates <- c("44933", "04/Feb/23", "45094", "26/May/23")
```

I've already tried some explanations I found in other posts but none of them seemed to work for me.

This is what I tried to do:

```
format_ymd  <- as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
format_dmy  <- as.Date(dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
as.Date(ifelse(is.na(format_ymd), format_dmy, format_ymd), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Comment: please post the other efforts you tried

Comment: for the numbers in the original vector are they days from a certain origin date? 44933 days from 1970 puts you in year 2093

Comment: @Mike they're all like 2021 to 2023

Comment: no problem please check the solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way to do it is to look for the `/` and then format them different than the numbers. the origin date seems to be the excel origin date of 1899-12-30 so I supplied that as the origin. after that it will return numbers with the origin date of 1970-01-01 so the last step is to convert them to dates.

```
dates <- c("44933", "04/Feb/23", "45094", "26/May/23")

dates2 <- ifelse(grepl("/",dates), 
       as.Date(dates, format = "%d/%b/%y"),
       as.Date(as.numeric(dates), origin = "1899-12-30"))

dates3 <- as.Date(dates2, origin = "1970-01-01")
```